Local Flutter Package Assets Won't Load Outside Package (Profile/Release)
I'm facing a peculiar problem where a local Flutter package I've developed works perfectly in debug mode, but fails to load assets when accessed from my main project in profile or release modes. Here's the relevant info:
Package: 'ordolib_core'
Holds my app's design system (images, fonts, etc.)
pubspec.yaml:
name: ordolib_core
description: "A package that encapsulates all the shared UI-code for ordo'lib apps"
version: 0.0.1
environment:
sdk: ">=3.2.3 <4.0.0"
flutter: ">=1.17.0"
... (dependencies listed)
flutter:
uses-material-design: true
assets:
- lib/assets/images/
- assets/fonts/
fonts:
- family: TT Norms Pro
# ... (font definitions)
- family: ordoLibIcons
# ... (font definitions)
Main Project: 'example'
pubspec.yaml:
name: example
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: "none"
version: 0.1.0
environment:
sdk: ">=3.2.3 <4.0.0"
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
ordolib_core:
path: ../
... (other dependencies)
The Issue: I can access ordolib_core assets without any problem in debug mode. However, in profile or release builds, they're nowhere to be found.
Double-checked pubspec.yaml asset declarations in both projects.
Attempted forced cache invalidation (flutter clean, etc.).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
